# Integrate Bootstrap on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'm trying to  use bootstrap on a codeigniter web but it looks like the bootstrap files are not found

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url('application/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('application/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"></script>
```

I've checked the paths generated by base_url()  and it are correct.

Comment: Please `view source` of your webpage by `ctrl + u` and see that the file is included or not? and then adjust URL as needed .. Thats how I do

Comment: The files are included and the paths are correct

Comment: If you click on that file link from Page Source and the file opens, then it should be working :)

Comment: `base_url` will defaultly included `application` folder.No need to give again `application`.Remove `application` and try.

Comment: You need to create a assets folder in main directory you cannot access through  the applications unless modify application htaccess which is set as deny all

Answer (score 18, accepted):

move `bootstrap` folder on root location, because CI is understanding `application` folder as `controller` although application folder is restricted from client request by `/application/.htaccess` file

```
|-
   |-application
   |-bootstrap

//and use path as
<?php echo base_url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>
```

Comment: That is the most right answer. The `.htaccess` inside `application/` won't allow to serve content from that folder.

Comment: even better if CDN version can be used, in order to leverage caching & speed up loading process.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the best guide I've found so far:
[How to include bootstrap in CI](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/06/integrate-twitter-bootstrap3-with-codeigniter-framework.html)

In short:

1. Download bootstrap
2. Put it in an assets folder on same level as application folder
3. Also put jquery
4. Include css in header and jquery in footer of your templates:

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>       <title>CodeIgniter Tutorial</title>
>       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
>   </head>
>   <body>
>       <h1>H_E_A_D_E_R</h1>
> ```

and :

```
<hr/>
<em>&copy; 2016</em>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to include the CodeIgniter URL helper in your controller

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: This is an important step for those getting the "undefined function base_url()" error.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing over here so that you no need to combine folders manually. I used this package offered from github regularly to commit new projects. Of course you will have to modify the application/config/config.php to get things work !

https://github.com/sjlu/CodeIgniter-Bootstrap

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a folder(assets) in Codeigniter root directly (Same level to application folder)
2. Paste your bootstrap files into that folder
3. add link code in your view file

   ```
   <link type="text/css" href="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```
4. add this line in your controller file **application/cotrollers/test.php**

   ```
   <?php
   class Test extends CI_Controller {

   public function index()
     {
      $this->load->helper('url'); // Load url links
      $this->load->view('index'); //Load view page
     }

   }
   ?>
   ```
5. Now you can use bootstrap classes in your view

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Bootstrap file from the internet if you want to work offline
2. Unzip and rename and copy to root folder. If you put it in application folder, .htaccess will not allow it to be accessed.
3. Add the link like the following line of code:

   ```
   <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?> rel="stylesheet">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Ci4 , add the folder 'bootstrap' in the default folder 'public'.

Thanks