# codeigniter return 404 error while add path to offline bootstrap

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

This error occurs when I enter this code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("asserts/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[image: this is my error]

[Integrate Bootstrap on CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29794513/integrate-bootstrap-on-codeigniter).
These answers are not working for me

Comment: set correct base url in config file. then it will work fine

Comment: But it has got the error "404 Not Found" for bootstrap.min.css

Comment: make sure path is correct. is that Assets folder or Asserts. check it.

Comment: You need to set the base url in config.php

Comment: `asserts` is not `assets`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting correct result you should set base_url first inside **application/config/config.php**

like below

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
   //codigniter is demo project. set your own;
```

after that you should check weather you have loaded url helper or not. 
to do that go to **application/config/autoload.php** and set the url like below

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

finally check you have successfully set directory of css file inside **base_url()** function. hope that, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Use *lower case* name for your directories and your path.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

some platforms are case sensitive.

Comment: Clarification: I changed `asserts` to `assets` because that is what is commonly used (and makes semantic sense).

Answer (score 0):

Set the base_url in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/FirstApp/';
```

Reason if you do not some assets and links will not work.